# ACE editor "Cannot read property 'getValue' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ace-editor

I am currently building a markdown editor in Angular.

- [ACE editor](https://ace.c9.io/) is used as a code editor.
- the npm package is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ace-builds

A codesandbox can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/angular-91d27

---

The problem is that I am trying to get the current value in order to further work with it.
The concept is that whenever the code will change (`onChange()`) the content is put into an Angular Service.

For testing purposes I want to print the current content onChange.

```
this.codeEditor.on("change", function(e) {
    const code = this.codeEditor.getValue();
    console.log(code);
});
```

Now whenever I am typing something I get the following error:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of undefined`

If anybody encountered this before I would be glad for some help.
Also I am wondering if this is "the right way" to handle this, or if there are better options.

Comment: how did you get code editor instance? is it in typescript? if yes can you please comment how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every new function defines its own `this` scope. Try using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead. Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so `this` actually refers to the originating context.

```
this.codeEditor.on("change", (e) => {
    const code = this.codeEditor.getValue();
    console.log(code);
});
```

Comment: So in the original version it would look like a method of `getValue()` inside the new function? Since `this` refers to the new function. An an arrow function does not create it's own scope. Wow thanks. Can't accept now. But I will as soon as possible.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer helped you kindly mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: The question is too new. I will as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks. glad I could be of help :)